# How to Navigate between xaml controls of UWP using mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am developing a UWP application in which I have several XAML controls(buttons, textblocks, checkboxes, etc). Ideally, The final user of this app should be able to navigate between these controls ONLY USING MOUSE WHEEL(this is a medical device UI in which only a mouse wheel will be available on top of the monitor). Now my question is that how to force this application use mouse wheel as the primary source of navigation between controls?

Some more feedbacks:

1.Right now, when I run my application in visual studio, I just see mouse pointer and of course buttons are sensitive to mouse clicks but in order to initiate an event, I have to hover to that element and click. MOUSE WHEEL IS NOT WORKING by default to navigate and select controls.

2.when I sideload this UWP application on a raspberry pi device and run the application there, the only way to navigate between controls is using an attached keyboard(possible to navigate and select controls using it). AGAIN ATTACHED MOUSE WHEEL IS NOT WORKING HERE.

3. an example of controls I use in my code is this:

xaml code:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1" Click="button1_click" />

 <Button x:Name="button2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button2" Click="button2_click" />

 <Button x:Name="button3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button3" Click="button3_click" />
```

c# code:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//do sth
}
 private void button2_click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//do sth
}
 private void button3_click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//do sth
}
```

in above code, it is not possible to navigate between three buttons using mouse wheel(both in visual studio and raspberry pi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AGAIN ATTACHED MOUSE WHEEL IS NOT WORKING HERE.

How did you register the 'MOUSE WHEEL' event in your code? It worked well on my side.

Please see the following code sample:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="root" >
    <Button x:Name="button1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1" Click="button1_click" />

    <Button x:Name="button2"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button2" Click="button2_click" />

    <Button x:Name="button3"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button3" Click="button3_click" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerWheelChanged += CoreWindow_PointerWheelChanged;
}

private async void CoreWindow_PointerWheelChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.CurrentPoint.Properties.MouseWheelDelta);
    UIElement element;
    if (args.CurrentPoint.Properties.MouseWheelDelta > 0)
    {
        element = FocusManager.FindNextFocusableElement(FocusNavigationDirection.Up);
        if (element == null)
        {
            element = FocusManager.FindLastFocusableElement(root) as UIElement;
        }
        var result = await FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(element, FocusState.Keyboard);
        Debug.WriteLine((element as Button).Content.ToString() + " focused: " + result.Succeeded);
    }
    else
    {
        element = FocusManager.FindNextFocusableElement(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
        if (element == null)
        {
            element = FocusManager.FindFirstFocusableElement(root) as UIElement;
        }
        var result = await FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(element, FocusState.Keyboard);
        Debug.WriteLine((element as Button).Content.ToString() + " focused: " + result.Succeeded);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an idea.
First you should handle tabIndex properties of all of those Items on form and set their order. also whats being triggered with you will move with the tab in your case with mouse wheel gonna be "Focused" or "GotFocus" method. so an event like "GotFocus" will be needed. also you need to handle mouse wheel movements(up or down). you may google about how to override TabIndex property from tab Key to Mouse wheel as you want.

Comment: i am not that similiar with UWP. generally running with windows forms but you may try out TabIndex properties of items you ve added in xaml.this option should be exist on default.

Comment: There is a built in focus Enter and Leave on Windows forms and on the android side i ve checked that even there we have Focused and Unfocused events. so thats your point go with that and work with breakpoints

Comment: thanks! I did not find anything online regarding overriding TabIndex property from tab Key with Mouse wheel!!!

Comment: my bad. TabIndex is an enumeration for order of controls when you press tab. you may google for if form has a mouse wheel event or how to handle mouse wheel events.  if user turns the wheel send a Tab key message to form with SendKey() method. so with this you can reach your purpose i guess